# Toggle background of multiple table cells while mouse botton clicked

Tags: jquery

I have a weekly calendar, where I want to highlight multiple hours with one "mousedown + move over cells + mouseup". And again remove highlight (invert) the same way.

http://jsfiddle.net/yTd4Q/13/

Comment: Can you clarify your question and/or provide a simple example? More detail would be useful.

Comment: This depends, to an extent, on exactly what your table looks like. Please post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to track whether the mouse is down. This is a simple way of doing it.

http://jsfiddle.net/EZLxv/2/

```
var mousedown = false;

$(document).mousedown( function() { mousedown = true; });
$(document).mouseup( function() { mousedown = false; });

$('td').mousedown( function() { $(this).addClass('active'); });

$('td').mouseover( function() {
    if (mousedown) { $(this).addClass('active'); }
});
```

Comment: That's almost it, but I need to change td color only when button is pressed.

Comment: That is exaclty what it does. The td color only changes when the button is held down and you drag the mouse over the cells. Otherwise I misunderstand your question.

Comment: Thanks, I used your example in my code - http://jsfiddle.net/yTd4Q/13/. However, there seem to be some interference with browser - it highlights the text. How to avoid this?

Comment: add `return false` to the document mousedown handler. I tested this in Chrome and IE9. I can't guarantee how reliable something like this will be. You may want to ask it in another SO question. Then someone with more expertise can chime in. http://jsfiddle.net/yTd4Q/15/